# Drupal folders within docker

Tags: docker, drupal, drupal-7

I succesfully installed drupal 7 with docker.

Using docker4drupal, now my question when I start editing my drupal site is, where are the folders containing drupal?

Let's say I installed a new theme and want to swap the images for the banner, how do I access the drupal folder containing the images, or would it be preciser to ask : Where does Docker storage them?

My docker compose line is :

`-codebase : /var/www/html`

I know that installing it using :

`./:/var/www/html`

Would install drupal in the same directory my docker-compose.yml is, but for some reason it doesn't work and still doesn't show me where the files are.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using volumes to mount your existing code, the code resides inside the docker container. You can access it only by getting inside the container using docker exec.   If you are using the default docker-compose.yml that came with the repo, then the name of the container will be "docker4drupal_nginx_1" (since nginx is the default).

Run this code to get inside the container:

```
docker exec -it docker4drupal_nginx_1 /bin/bash
```

**exec** allows you to execute commands inside the container.

**-it** allows you to start an interactive terminal

**/bin/bash** allows you to start the bash terminal inside the container

Once you are inside container run ls and you will see drupal files including "web".

**MORE USEFUL**

However, this is not a useful way if you want to work on the files and probably use an editor. Instead, mount a directory on host machine.  First make a new directory where your docker-compose.yml file is with the name "codebase".

Then, update the docker-compose.yml so that:

```
- codebase:/var/www/html
```

becomes

```
- ./codebase:/var/www/html
```

Do this in both php and nginx service definisions. Of course, you should do this after you run **docker-compose down** with your previous set up. Then restart containers using **docker-compose up -d**.

Then, you will notice that the Drupal files are present in the codebase directory.

If you see at the bottom of the yml file, you will see that "codebase" is defined as a Docker volume. This implies the storage is managed by Docker and it will get stored somewhere in /var/lib/docker/ along with the container itself.

Hope this helps.